# Hi. How i can create bootstrap borderet table like this

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like the first two columns to only occupy the width of their contents, and for the final 3rd column to be justified to the right with a gap (if any) between the 2nd and 3rd columns as immediately below. In the diagram I have marked this as a large empty column.

```
+-------+------+-------------------+------+
| Col1  | Col2 |                   | Col3 |
+-------+------+-------------------+------+
| Val 1 | Val2 |                   | Val3 |
+-------+------+-------------------+------+
```

Some restraints:

- I can use only bootstrap.
- I cant use any custom styles.

I've tried it as follows, but it's not working.

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="row">
             <td class="col-md-1">col1</td>
             <td class="col-md-1">col2</td>
             <td class="col-md-9"></td>
             <td class="col-md-1">col3</td>
        </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
        <tr class="row">
             <td class="col-md-1">val1</td>
             <td class="col-md-1">val2</td>
             <td class="col-md-9"></td>
             <td class="col-md-1">val3</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: stackoverflow broke the description of table (

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Bootstrap 3

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Check which version you are using for bootstrap. If any of the above code is not working please check you imported the bootstrap properly or not.